# FutureBuilder doesn't wait for future to complete

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am using API call to get data and display in a ListView.

Here is the future builder class:

```
Widget futureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
      future: _getProjects(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        debugPrint('Builder');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              return listWidget(snapshot);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is, debugPrint('Builder') is called even before _getProjects() returns result, so snapshot is passed as null in my ListView Widget.

Here is _getProjects() class:

```
Future<List<Project>> _getProjects() async {
    List<Project> projects = [];
    String getProjects = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g3xpe";
    var response = await http.get(getProjects);
    Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
    projects = list.map((model) => Project.fromJson(model)).toList();
    debugPrint('Size ' + projects.length.toString());
    return projects;
  }
```

Here is the full code:

```
class Projects extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ProjectState createState() => new ProjectState();
}

class ProjectState extends State {

   Future<List<Project>> _getProjects() async {
    List<Project> projects = [];
    String getProjects = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g3xpe";
    var response = await http.get(getProjects);
    Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
    projects = list.map((model) => Project.fromJson(model)).toList();
    debugPrint('Size ' + projects.length.toString());
    return projects;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      primary: true,
      appBar: EmptyAppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          headerWidget(),
          futureBuilder()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget futureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
      future: _getProjects(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        debugPrint('Builder');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              return listWidget(snapshot);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}



Widget headerWidget() {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
    child: Container(
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12)),
            Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black54),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12)),
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.loose,
              child: searchBar(),
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12)),
          ],
        )),
  );
}

Widget searchBar() {
  return Container(
    height: 52,
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
    child: TextField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        filled: false,
        hasFloatingPlaceholder: false,
        hintText: 'Search here',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget listWidget(AsyncSnapshot<List<Project>> snapshot) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            listItem(snapshot.data[index]);
          },
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length));
}

Widget listItem(Project project) {
  return Card(
    elevation: 6.0,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[Text('Project ID'), Text('Project Name')],
    ),
  );
}

class EmptyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I made some changes to FutureBuilder:

```
Widget futureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
      future: _getProjects(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        debugPrint('Builder');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else
              return listWidget(snapshot);
            break;

          default:
            debugPrint("Snapshot " + snapshot.toString());
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I am getting this error now:

```
I/flutter ( 4054): _FutureBuilderState<List<Project>>#67dc4):
I/flutter ( 4054): A build function returned null.
I/flutter ( 4054): The offending widget is: FutureBuilder<List<Project>>
I/flutter ( 4054): Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to
I/flutter ( 4054): fill available room, return "new Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as
I/flutter ( 4054): possible, return "new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
```

And SnapShot in default is returning this Snapshot AsyncSnapshot>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)

Comment: in your switch why you want to use state `none` and `waiting`?

Comment: Just for debugging purpose. And more importantly, they were there in the code that I got from internet.

Comment: do you know how `switch` works? if you are not sure how to use `FutureBuilder` then read its [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) - it has some working sample code

Comment: Yes. The think is, debugPrint('Builder') is called before Future returns result.

Comment: did you check the link to the documentation i posted? if so, whats unclear in the sample code they provide?

Comment: @pskink  made a few changes. And added error I am getting in my original post

Comment: `default` case returns null: `"I/flutter ( 4054):  A build function returned null."`

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the help. After few workouts, I understood the error and made it to work. Thanks for the way you helped instead of spoon feeding. Really appreciate that. Cheers!!

Comment: sure, your welcome, thats why i dont give a fish - i give a fishing rod instead ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if there is any data returned by the AsyncSnapshot (snapshot).
Add a `if`statement like this:

```
if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
//rest of your code
}
else {
//show progress indicator or error...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I/flutter ( 4054): A build function returned null.

You always need to return a widget from a builder, no matter what:

```
Widget futureBuilder() {
        return FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
          future: _getProjects(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            debugPrint('Builder');
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                else
                  return listWidget(snapshot);
                break;

              default:
                debugPrint("Snapshot " + snapshot.toString());
              return Container() // also check your listWidget(snapshot) as it may return null.
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

> The issue is, debugPrint('Builder') is called even before
>   _getProjects() returns result, so snapshot is passed as null in my ListView Widget.

This is normal, think for example if you have a long task ( a request or some really long calculation), you will need to display a loading until that future is "done". Also, putting something to be executed on a "future", means that it is ok for you to have it executed "later on", otherwise you need to use **await**.